# What cause the "Recipient field contains invalid device token"?

Tags: certificates, mobilepush-ios

I've been working on creating a simple connected App, that can receive Apple Push Notification.
For that I:
Created an Xcode project using force iOS.
Used Keychain Access to create 2 CSR file, and used the Apple Developer Program to create Certificates (One for The App, using a CSR, and the other for the Push functionality using the other CSR).
I Created Provisioning Profile with MyApp and my phone (Real device). 
I enabled the Push functionality in Xcode and I was able to see in Salesforce my device Registration when I log into my App.

The problem occurs when I try to send A Test Push Notification From Salesforce. I choose as the recipient the Token from the previous registration. But the answer is always : "Recipient field contains invalid device token".
I suspect that this is not so much a problem on the Token, but a problem on the certificate I use.

I've been looking all other the net to see how to build this .P12 Certificate, but all the different ways I found, always lead to the same error (Except when I create really bad Certificate, obviously.).

Could someone help me out figuring out what this error is really about and how to fix it?

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

Ok, one of my colleagues figured out what the problem was.
It was coming from the Bundle ID. The Bundle Id must end with the application name.
I had my application package that looked like com.test.validation and my app was pushnotification.
So the BundleId needs to be com.test.validation.pushnotification, and not just com.test.validation like what I was doing.

Comment: Sound painful. And people complain about Apex....